# sympy (99/16 < n) & (n < oo) : iwant element

Tags: python, sympy

sympy logical operation ?

i try

```
from sympy import *
var('n')
f=(99/16 < n) & (n < oo)
print("#",type(f))
print("#",f)
print("#",simplify(f))
# And
# (n > 6.1875) & (n < oo)
# (n > 6.1875) & (n < oo)
```

i want to print  99/16 < n

i want to print &

i want to print (n < oo)

i want to print 99/16

i want to print oo

how do i display decimals as fractions?

string ok

(2022-02-16) i try:Declare n with real=True

```
from sympy import *
n = Symbol('n', real=True)
f=(99/16 < n) & (n < oo)
print("#",type(f))
print("#",f)
print("#",simplify(f))
# <class 'sympy.core.relational.StrictGreaterThan'>
# n > 6.1875
# n > 6.1875
```

(2022-02-17)str

```
from sympy import *
var('n')
f=(99/16 < n) & (n < oo)
print("#",    f )
print("#",str(f))
# (n > 6.1875) & (n < oo)
# (n > 6.1875) & (n < oo)
```

(2022-02-18) S() method

```
from sympy import *
print("#",  99/   16 )
print("#",S(99)/  16 )
print("#",  99 /S(16))
print("#",S(99 /  16))
# 6.1875
# 99/16
# 99/16
# 6.18750000000000
```

Comment: Declare `n` with `real=True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working within Python, 99/16 is a Python float. To get it into SymPy you have to make one of the values a SymPy number.

```
>>> from sympy import S, oo
>>> from sympy.abc import n
>>> (S(99)/16 < n) & (n < oo)
(99/16 < n) & (n < oo)
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-s-method/
Syntax : sympy.S()
Return : Return the single instance of an object.

Comment: `S(99)` creates `Integer(99)` and then division by 16 creates `Rational(99, 16)`. Without the `S` to "get you into SymPy mode" you just create the float and that float gets converted to Float when you use the `< n` with it.