# sympy preorder_traversal: i want to choice ...tGreaterThan element

Tags: sympy

2way?

① i want to choice ...tGreaterThan element ----> n > 6.1875

②I can convert it to a string and use a regular expression.

preorder_traversal < Walking the Tree
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/manipulation.html#walking-the-tree

i try

```
from sympy import *
var('n')
f=(99/16 < n) & (n < oo)
for arg in preorder_traversal(f):
    print("#",arg,"____",type(arg))
# (n > 6.1875) & (n < oo) ____ And
# n < oo ____ <class 'sympy.core.relational.StrictLessThan'>
# n ____ <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
# oo ____ <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Infinity'>
# n > 6.1875 ____ <class 'sympy.core.relational.StrictGreaterThan'>
# n ____ <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
# 6.18750000000000 ____ <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>
```

ref)

japanese only

https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/74249/sympy%E3%81%AE1%E5%A4%89%E6%95%B0%E4%B8%8D%E7%AD%89%E5%BC%8F-inequality-solvers-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6%E6%95%99%E3%81%88%E3%81%A6%E4%B8%8B%E3%81%95%E3%81%84

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking for but if you declare `n` to be real (and therefore *finite*) then this will simplify automatically:

```
In [5]: n = symbols('n', real=True)

In [6]: f=(99/16 < n) & (n < oo)

In [7]: f
Out[7]: n > 6.1875
```

Comment: You can also select this argument from f with `f.args[0]` or `f.args[1]`.

Comment: ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71141821/sympy-99-16-n-n-oo-iwant-element/71144978#71144978